# Accessing Properties of a collection, WITHOUT use of for...each loop, in VBScript

Tags: collections, vbscript, foreach

I currently have the below code, but obviously I am not that skilled on working with collections. Hence I cannot seem to work out how to get each name value, out of the rule property, in each round of the loop.

```
dim c,ExistingRules
set objFWP = createobject("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")
set colRules = objFWP.rules

for c = 1 to colRules.count - 1
   ExistingRules = ExistingRules & colRules(c).name
next
```

In place of `colRules(c).name`, I have tried things like:

- `colRules.item(c).name`
- `colRules.name(c)`
- `t = colRules.name / t(c)`

... etc

Despite researching how to iterate through a collection without for...each on the web, and learn more about how to work with collections, I am sure that the community here could help me out with a solution/sources to learn more quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Rules` object is an instance of the COM interface [`INetFwRules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As it turns out, there is no way to retrieve an item from this collection by index. The definition of the [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method
shows that it retrieves the rule by **name**.  So in this particular case, you *must* use `For Each ... In`.

```
Dim rule
For Each rule In colRules
   WScript.Echo "Rule: " & rule.Name
Next
```

---

If you want to break the loop early and then re-enumerate, you need to reassign the rules collection:

```
Dim rule
Dim colRules

Set colRules = objFWP.Rules
WScript.Echo "Loop first time..."
For Each rule In colRules
   WScript.Echo "Rule: " & rule.Name
   Exit For
Next

' Reassign colRules
Set colRules = objFWP.Rules
WScript.Echo "Loop again..."
For Each rule In colRules
   WScript.Echo "Rule: " & rule.Name
   Exit For
Next
```

Comment: Darn. So no way to move index on (Like you would in an ADO recordset), or reset the index? Main reason for wanting to iterate with a counter was it seems breaking the loop, then starting same loop again doesn't reset back to the first "record".

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem like I can re-edit my above comment. The above was supposed to be a question.

Comment: The way to get around that seems to be not reusing the original INetFwRules variable. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
set objFWP = createobject("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")
set colRules = objFWP.rules

' because index in VBScript is zero based
for c = 0 to colRules.count - 1
   'assuming name is one of the property for items in the collection 
   ExistingRules = ExistingRules & colRules.ItemIndex(c).name 
next
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work - `Error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'colRules.ItemIndex'`/ http://i.imgur.com/ZVy3tny.png . Would kindly suggest that when answering someone's question assumptions are not made, and instead theories tried prior to posting.